# Where do I need to pass request?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

When I click on the button, I am trying to activate a function that will transfer data to the template and open it.
Here is the button click function:

```
function openForm () {

    const amount = select.value;

    $ .ajax ({
        url: '/ create_order /',
        type: 'get',
        data: {'amount': amount},
        dataType: "json",
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data ['content']) {
                $ ('body'). append (data ['content']);
                console.log (data ['content'])
            }
        },
    });
}
```

urls.py

```
url (r '^ create_order /', CreateOrder),
```

views.py

```
def CreateOrder (amount, request):
    count = amount.GET.dict ()

    content = mark_safe (render_to_string (
        'form.html',
        {
            'amount': count ['amount'],
        },
        request))
```

The question is in the request parameter. I need it in the last line, so I need to pass it to the CreateOrder function. But this is how the error occurs

```
TypeError at / create_order / ↵CreateOrder () missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Tell me how can I pass request in the `openForm ()` function or how to do it correctly differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the urls.py

```
url (r '^ create_order /', CreateOrder),
```

This will call the `CreateOrder (amount, request):` passing in the place of the first argument `amount` the `request` request that was made (not any number)

you need to change your **urls.py** to instead have an extra parameter `amount` after the **/**

```
from django.urls import path

path(r '^ create_order /<int:amount>', CreateOrder), #takes a number after the slash
```

This will then call your functions properly passing as arguments `amount` and `request` respectively.

**EDIT** : The first argument must be `request` not `amount` so you must change it to

```
def CreateOrder (request,amount):
```

Comment: I do this `path ('create_order / <int: amount>', CreateOrder),` but my debugger doesn't even go into CreateOrder and responseText is like `<! DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv = "content-type" content = "text / html; charset = utf-8">
  <title> Page not found at / create_order / </title>`

Comment: You need to perform the **Ajax** in `/create_order/<int:amount>/` right now you are doing it in `create_order/` which is not found, also not sure if it is an issue, watch your spaces.

Comment: I am a beginner specialist, so I very much apologize for the stupidity) here is JavaScript 
   ` $.ajax({
        url: '/create_order/',
        type: 'get',
        data: {'amount': amount},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data['content']) {
                $('body').append(data['content']);
                console.log(data['content'])
            }
        },
    });
}`  here are urls `path('/create_order/<int:amount>', CreateOrder),` and all the same error. What's wrong, please help?

Comment: `{ url: '/create_order/${amount}'` This will append the amount to the current **URL** something like `create_order/5000` and the `def CreateOrder (request,amount):` will now have `amount` as an argument. But from what I understand you don't really need to append  the `amount` to the current **URL** so a better idea would be to remove it completely from the view and the url and just acess the data via `amount = request.GET.get("amount")`.

Comment: Thank you very much! And what to do with this error, do not tell me please? What HttpResponse would be the right way to return?

`ValueError at / create_order / ↵The view project.views.CreateOrder didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: This is unrelated to the base question, check the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/) for writting views, they should return a **response**